# Cannot resolve symbol #:: error for streams in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-streams

I have been trying the Bloxorz assignment as part of the *Functional Program Design in Scala* course and have been trying to add an element to a Stream as below but I am getting:

> Cannot resolve symbol `#::`.

There is some very small, obvious mistake in this code. What am I doing wrong here?

```
def neighborsWithHistory(b: Block, history: List[Move]): Stream[(Block, List[Move])] = {
  (b.neighbors foldLeft Stream((b, history))) {
    case (acc, (bl, move)) => acc #:: (bl, move :: history)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods ending with a colon are [*right associative*](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#infix-types). Since `#::` is defined as a `ConsWrapper` on a `Stream`, your `acc` needs to be on the right hand side:

```
(bl, move :: history) #:: acc
```

Comment: Ohh. I spent half an hour missing this detail. Thanks a lot. It works :)